# dead battery in a Dell laptop

Tags: dell-inspiron

I have a Dell Inspiron 15 and the battery has been dead for a while so I have been using AC. Well now my laptop will not load the home screen. I can not get any icons or start up menu. Will replacing the battery fix this problem?

Comment: Your computer not loading is not connected to the status of your battery.

Comment: When exactly does it stop loading? What OS are you using? Is the battery inserted into laptop? Does removing the battery and connecting AC power help?

Comment: Has the battery been removed?  If not, do so (while unplugged and turned off), and then see how it works.  Very often the computer power controller will refuse to allow the system to run if the battery is installed but seems defective.

Answer (score 1):

No. If your regular power is working then you have another problem.

You can always verify this by removing the battery and then booting the laptop.
If you have a second laptop or a second [PSU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_supply_unit_%28computer%29) (of comparable type) then make sure that the PSU or the power sockets on your laptop has not died.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this before where the computer won't turn on at all. The times I've seen it, I've had to unplug power, remove battery, then hold down the power button for about 15-30 seconds, up to 60 couldn't hurt. Then I was able to reconnect power and it started up with no problem. The tech bulletin that I had read attributed the problem to static build up, but who knows...

If the computer is turning on but your operating system is not loading, then that is a different unrelated problem.

Answer (score 0):

No, it won't. The battery just provides power, as does the AC. If it does not work with one, it will not work with the other.

Comment: What if the battery is dead, and the new one isn't? Tricky tricky :P

Comment: @CanadianLuke the one and the other in question are the battery and the AC power. If it does not run when plugged in, it won't with a new battery either.

Comment: If the AC adapter is dead, it won't charge the battery and have the same symptoms

Comment: @CanadianLuke ah, yes, if the AC adapter is dead that might be a problem. Still, if that is the case a new battery will make no difference because it won't be able to charge.

Comment: But the new battery may be semi-charged... I'm just making you work for the answer :P

Comment: @CanadianLuke grrr, and anyway, the little gnomes that are killing the machine might just switch to the new battery. :)

Answer (score 0):

if you remove the battery and switch the charger to a laptop, then the laptop must booting.

If the laptop does not boot then the problem is not in the battery

Answer (score 0):

Did you check your ram???

I had a problem where the battery was needing replaced in my Inspiron 1545, so I always used it plugged into the wall. I ignored the "your battery is dead" message. Then one day, it wouldn't turn on at all.  I would push the power button and hear it try to start but it wouldn't...after about 3 seconds there was no sound. I thought it must be related to the power/battery, but it wasn't.

The power led light would be on, but no screen power, no boot.  Realizing I still got power, I figured a serious problem. Apparently it was getting power but not booting.

I opened the back and took out my two 2G ram cards and reset them -- thinking perhaps a connection was bad.  No difference.  Then I swapped the places of the two ram cards.  It worked.  Apparently one ram card was bad and one was good.  So now it was just figuring out which ram card worked and which was bad -- pretty easy just to try one at a time, and try to reboot.  My lap top can adequately function with one 2G ram card, but I ordered a replacement card (2G for about $26).  I'm SO happy this is a $26 fix as I'm a nursing student and absolutely cannot afford a new laptop right now.

I think it's weird that it'll stop working if just one ram card is dysfunctional.  But it will...so check your ram cards one at a time.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem where my laptop would power off and refuse to boot.  But curiously it ran fine with the battery removed and powered only from the "brick" AND it also ran fine when only on battery power.  Just not both.

Finally figured out the power controller thought the battery was being overcharged and was trying to prevent that.  Running the battery down to 20% or so before plugging in the brick solved it temporarily, and playing with the power management settings fixed it permanently.

In this case I'd suspect that the power controller knows that the battery is defective and is trying to prevent a possible problem (eg, fire).  So unplugging the battery may be a temporary "fix".

Answer (score 0):

Mine is that, my dell latitude e5440 has light on power button when I press it, the light come on for like 13 seconds and goes off again but black screen. Someone told me it's something on the motherboard that I need to change for my pc to work. Though I've been using the laptop as desktop, no battery. I don't know if that was the cause

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).